# (Instagram) Scrape All Facebook places_id 's in a region from without access token

Tags: json, facebook, facebook-graph-api, web-scraping, instagram-api

How do I find all of the facebook_places_id's in Brooklyn? I need them to scrape Instagram's public website.

I am able to lookup places_id's for a single location by name. I am also able to query all photos/videos and metadata once I have the location ID. All of this is available without needing an access token.

**Look up facebook_places_id 's**
This url allows you to look up location_ids by name. For example, this returns close matches for "Brooklyn, New York" (you can enter this into any browser and see the result, no access key or login required. I recommend Firefox):

```
https://www.instagram.com/web/search/topsearch/?context=place&query=brooklyn+new+york
```

From the JSON returned, we can see that "Brooklyn, New York" has the facebook_places_id 212950988

**Scrape metadata for a given facebook_places_id**

This url will return JSON metadata about posts in Brooklyn:

```
https://www.instagram.com/graphql/query/?query_id=17881432870018455&id=212950988&first=12&after=0"
```

So I can get everything I want if I know the place, I just need a full list of places to ask for.

Answer (score 0):

```
https://www.instagram.com/web/search/topsearch/?context=place&query=brooklyn+new+york
```

The `id` you get from the above API call is not `facebook_places_id`, it is `instagram_location_id` that you use in API call to get location posts.

Below is Facebook Graph API call to get `facebook_places_id` in one city or region specified by lat,lng and distance. However this required a facebook access_token

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=coffee&type=place&center=45.5230622,-122.67648150000002&distance=5000&access_token=XXX
```

You can get the list of facebook_places_id and then use the below API call to get corresponding `instagram_location_id`, which you can use to get location posts data.

```
https://api.instagram.com/v1/locations/search?facebook_places_id=694471784029871&access_token=XXX
```

This API call requires a instagram `access_token`